# Embedding Audio Files using HTML 5 or something else?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, mp3

I have been looking around for a way to embed MP3 Audio files to be played on my webpage. I found W3 Schools HTML 5 but my concern is browser compatibility.

HTML 5 Code:

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    Your browser does not support this audio format.
</audio>
```

You can find it here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_sounds.asp

The problem is it only played on like IE 9+ which will be a problem. Can someone please tell me what the best way to play audio files on a way page or even possibly playing using a third party software.

Is using Embed tags such as this better then using HTML5?

```
<embed height="50" width="100" src="horse.mp3">
```

Most importantly what I use to embed need to work on at least IE 7 plus your other browsers (chrome, safari, firefox etc...)

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This library support all browsers : [audio.js](http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/)

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, I know. But for completeness's sake I would like to mention that there is this excellent [mediaelement.js by John Dyer](http://mediaelementjs.com/).

It works with many file formats (including mp3, depending on client capabilities) and most browsers. I use it in one of my projects.